# css checkbox not applying changes when in the :checked state

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I am trying to bring some hidden text into view when a radio checkbox is checked. I cant quite work out why the :checked styling is not applying once the label is checked. I think i am being really daft but just cant work out what is going on.

Could anyone lend some advice?

```css
.wrap__wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrap__radio--input {
  display: none;
}

.wrap__inner {
  width: 300%;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.wrap__slides {
  float: left;
  width: 33.333%;
}

.wrap__text {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrap__button {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.wrap__radio--input:checked~.wrap__inner {
  transition: all 1s;
  background: red;
  left: -100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap__wrapper">
  <div class="wrap">
    <input type="radio" class="wrap__radio--input" id="slide--1">
    <label for="slide--1" class="wrap__button">next slide</label>
    <div class="wrap__inner">
      <div class="wrap__slides">
        <p class="wrap__text">slide1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="wrap__slides">
        <p class="wrap__text">slide2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I will do yes, i was planning on just adding another button to each slide that would go back to the previous one. I just wanted to get the first one working first.

Comment: how would that work with 3 different slides? Surely i would need a button on each slide that would be set to go back to the one before rather than back to the start?

Comment: I'm planning on having 4 slides in total, i was thinking of having 2 checkboxes with labels setup on each slide so one would go back to the previous slide and one to move to the next one if that makes sense. Not done this before so a little learning curve for me :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your element need to be [positionned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) so you have to set `position` property to `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed` on `.wrap__inner` to be able to use left property. You cannot update position of static element.

```css
.wrap__wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrap__radio--input {
  display: none;
}

.wrap__inner {
  position:relative;
  width: 300%;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.wrap__slides {
  float: left;
  width: 33.333%;
}

.wrap__text {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrap__button {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.wrap__radio--input:checked~.wrap__inner {
  transition: all 1s;
  background: red;
  left: -100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap__wrapper">
  <div class="wrap">
  <input type="radio" class="wrap__radio--input" id="slide--1"> 
  <label for="slide--1" class="wrap__button">next slide</label>   
    <div class="wrap__inner">
      <div class="wrap__slides">
        <p class="wrap__text">slide1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="wrap__slides">
        <p class="wrap__text">slide2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="wrap__slides">
        <p class="wrap__text">slide3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much for this, i cant believe i missed the simple position element! brain freeze i think!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:before` or `:after` *pseudo-elements* to *toggle* the *previous* and *next* text, apply the `position` *property* different from the *default value* of *static* to the `.wrap__inner` *div* and most importantly change the `input type="radio"` to `input type="checkbox"` to be able to *toggle* the *checkbox* state:

```css
.wrap__wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrap__radio--input {
  display: none;
}

.wrap__inner {
  position: relative; /* any value other than default */
  width: 300%;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.wrap__slides {
  float: left;
  width: 33.333%;
}

.wrap__text {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrap__button {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

/* added */
.wrap__button:after {
  content: "next";
}

.wrap__radio--input:checked + .wrap__button:after {
  content: "previous";
}
/***/

.wrap__radio--input:checked ~ .wrap__inner {
  transition: all 1s;
  background: red;
  left: -100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap__wrapper">
  <div class="wrap">
    <input type="checkbox" class="wrap__radio--input" id="slide--1">
    <label for="slide--1" class="wrap__button"></label>
    <div class="wrap__inner">
      <div class="wrap__slides">
        <p class="wrap__text">slide1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="wrap__slides">
        <p class="wrap__text">slide2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Note:* Like I wrote in the comment, this only works for two slides.